# C++ / Code:Blocks issue with memory

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I getting error when compiling this code:

```
 int i[720][720];
```

error: Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD).

It is ok if I declare:

```
int i[719][719];
```

what happens?

EDIT:

Ok... I did like you said. It works now. I tried to correct code for multiply big numbers  [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971087/long-integer-multiplication).

I had to also change

```
        if(carry < 10){
            mat[i][j-(SIZE-1-i)]=carry;
            carry=0;
        }
```

to

```
        if(carry < 10){
            if (j-(SIZE-1-i) < 0) continue;
            mat[i][j-(SIZE-1-i)]=carry;
            carry=0;
        }
```

Comment: The array is too big to fit on the stack. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Or `new` or any other container (except `std::array` which would have the same effect).

Comment: Oh, ok... but is there any possibility to increase standard capacity of stack? I know that I need only [1000]x[1000] array.

Comment: Depends on the compiler.

Comment: mingw32 and c++11 flag

Comment: Increasing the stack size is probably not the right solution. What if someone else with another compiler will try to compile your code? You should use `std::vector` or `new`-allocated array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack is too small and you should be using dynamic allocation instead (e.g. `std::vector` or `new`). If you want to keep using stack allocation, you can increase stack size in compiler options or command line (depends on the compiler which you didn't state).

Comment: _"Your stack is probably too small"_ - `0xC00000FD` is a stack overflow exception so there is no _probably_ here.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your array is too big to store it in the standard stack space of your compiler. You can try to compile your code on the online Codechef compiler. It has very big capacity of stack. The link is: https://www.codechef.com/ide

Or ofcourse, you could use a vector using `std::vector` or dynamically alloctae your array using the `new` keyword (not very highly recommended).

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to create array of this size? 
To make it more memory efficient try using dynamic arrays declared using the keyword `new`. Example: `myArray = new int [10]`
They can expand according to your need and its memory efficient as well.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: @Till Looks like a little bit of both